# Vertices scales in the wrong direction

Tags: modeling, vertices, extrude, scale

Hello there community somewhat of a new user here...
I know I probably messed up some setting and, but whenever I extrude and scale vertices they move inwards of the model I dont know what I did or I am doing wrong but instead of scaling on the Y axis only it scales the edge inwards as well.
Any help is appreciated

Example:
Everything seems fine from the front side

[image: frontv]

No so from the right side....

[image: rightv]
How it should've been:
[image]
I got that curve while scaling it.Why am I getting it.

P.S I am following this tutorial as a guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SOwJDqoPTw&t

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots Sure, I've updated the post

Comment: I can't see your problem, could you please show with several screenshots?

Comment: @moonboots I've updated my question again

Comment: That is because your are simply pressing s . Solving - press s and press y to scale it on the y axis only. You are scaling it on all axis when you press  S. If that solves your problem please inform me to post it as the answer

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 Yep! it did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that is happening is that you have scaled it simply by pressing <kbd>S</kbd>  .
This is happening because while doing rotation, moving or scaling , blender considers the `origin` of the object as the `pivot point` for doing all the manipulations.

If you are wondering how the origin ( the one yellow point shown while selecting an object ) got away from the object's geometry you might have moved the object in the edit mode. **Remember that while in edit mode no matter whatever manipulations you do, the origin won't move along with the mesh as in edit mode**. To solve your problem you can simply scale it on the y axis by pressing<kbd>S</kbd>  + <kbd>Y</kbd> .The proper way to do it is by going to **object > set origin > origin to geometry** and then scale it by just pressing <kbd>S</kbd> 
[image]